# three.js object translate and rotate based on object self coordinate system or world coordinate system

Tags: three.js, coordinate-transformation

I create a cube in three.js and if i rotate it first then translateX,the cube position is not (10,0,0)

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 3, 3 );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000} );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set(0, 0 , 0);
mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
mesh.translateX(10);
scene.add( mesh );
```

[image: picture]

but if i translateX it first then rotate,the position is (10,0,0).

So i notice that object translate based on self coordinate system.
When i rotate first, the object self coordinate system has chenged.
But if i rotate it first then translateX,the cube position is (5.3, 0, -5.3),
and rotate it now , it looks like rotation not based on self coordinate system.

[image: png]

So i want to know is object translate and rotate based on self coordinate system or world coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A concatenation of 2 matrices (matrix multiplication) is not commutative:

Note, the translation matrix looks like this:

```
Matrix4x4 translate;

translate[0] : ( 1,  0,  0,  0 )
translate[1] : ( 0,  1,  0,  0 )
translate[2] : ( 0,  0,  1,  0 )
translate[3] : ( tx, ty, tz, 1 )
```

And the rotation matrix around Y-Axis looks like this:

```
Matrix4x4  rotate;
float      angle;

rotate[0] : ( cos(angle),  0, sin(angle), 0 )
rotate[1] : ( 0,           1, 0,          0 )
rotate[2] : ( -sin(angle), 0, cos(angle), 0 )
rotate[3] : ( 0,           0, 0,          1 )
```

A matrix multiplication works like this:

```
Matrix4x4 A, B, C;

// C = A * B
for ( int k = 0; k < 4; ++ k )
    for ( int l = 0; l < 4; ++ l )
        C[k][l] = A[0][l] * B[k][0] + A[1][l] * B[k][1] + A[2][l] * B[k][2] +  A[3][l] * B[k][3];
```

The result of `translate * rotate` is this:

```
model[0] : ( cos(angle),  0,  sin(angle), 0 )
model[1] : ( 0,           1,  0,          0 )
model[2] : ( -sin(angle), 0,  cos(angle), 0 )
model[3] : ( tx,          ty, tz,         1 )
```

[image]

Note, the result of `rotate * translate` would be:

```
model[0] : ( cos(angle),                     0,   sin(angle),                     0 )
model[1] : ( 0,                              1,   0,                              0 )
model[2] : ( -sin(angle),                    0,   cos(angle),                     0 )
model[3] : ( cos(angle)*tx - sin(angle)*tx,  ty,  sin(angle)*tz + cos(angle)*tz,  1 )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Rabbid76 , help a lot! so object rotation and translate based on self coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is based on the self coordinate system and that's why when you first rotate then there will be some angle between the universal axis and the object's axis and as it will translate on its own axis result will not match when you first translate when the axis was parallel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30544619)